# How can I make a box fit in a picture in css properly (view video to understand what i mean)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I want to put a screen behind an iphone X skin. How do I scale it so that it fits perfectly and adapts to zooming. The dark grey box is the screen. Basically, something like this is my endgoal. https://live.hqt.space/login

My HTML:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.xmple.com/wallpaper/linear-gradient-green-purple-1920x1080-c2-00ff7f-7b68ee-a-255-f-14.svg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.Containerforlogin {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: sticky;
  transform: translate(-50%,10%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="Containerforlogin">
  <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/34pi1c6.jpg" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to [inspect the element](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) and figure it out the [example](https://live.hqt.space/login) you gave?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is fit the image of the iPhone X screen into the div, one way to do it would be to change the position to absolute, and then the height and width to 100%. However, with your current code it is not possible to actually put text inside the iPhone X screen.

Here's my interpretation of what I think you're asking for:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Cold Hard Trivia </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Containerforlogin">
      <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/34pi1c6.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"> 
    </div>
    <div id="inside-phone-screen">Text for login</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://www.xmple.com/wallpaper/linear-gradient-green-purple-1920x1080-c2-00ff7f-7b68ee-a-255-f-14.svg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.Containerforlogin {
    width: 50vw;
    height:90vw;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,10%);
    position: sticky;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:10vw;
}
img {
    margin: auto;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#inside-phone-screen{
  padding:20% 10%;
}
```